# Error when saving fields with special characters using EntityFramework and MVC ModelBinding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-binding, valueinjecter

I am having problems with (2) fields when saving entities in my ASP.NET MVC4 application:

- email
- phone

As you know, these fields will have special characters `@` and `-` typically. Here is my code from the controller using ValueInjecter to inject my model classes from the hydrated object via Model Binding:

```
public ActionResult Create(TestViewModel testViewModel)
{
  using (var context = new MyEntities())
  {
    var person = new Person();
    person.InjectFrom(testViewModel);
    context.Person.AddObject(person);
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is the following:

> "String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated"

Ok on 1st glance you might say it's the size of the field in SQL, but the true issue is masqueraded because of those special charachters. If I enter the following for the fields:

phone: 11234565454514564561
email: blahblahblahblah

...then everything **works.**

However if I enter:

phone: 123-456-7890
email: test@wow.com

I get the error about the "String or binary data would be truncated". So I found a work-around but this seems completly unnecessary and probably the wrong way. If I explicitly map the values from the model bound object to the entity, using the C# escape characters, then my values will insert as shown below:

```
public ActionResult Create(TestViewModel testViewModel)
{
  using (var context = new MyEntities())
  {
    var person = new Person();
    person.InjectFrom(testViewModel);

    //Explicitly map items preserving special charachters
    person.EmailAddress = @testViewModel.EmailAddress;
    person.Phone = @testViewModel.Phone;

    context.Person.AddObject(person);
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
}
```

OK, so honestly I don't know where the culprit lies. Is this a MVC model binding issue, an Entity Framework issue, a C# deal, or ValueInjecter? I tried using annotations on my ViewModel properties to dictate the data types like `Phone` and `Email` but that didn't stop the issue. Only by being explicit in code by escaping those characters was a way to do it.

What am I doing incorrectly because I know fields like email and phone with special characters are saved off all the time to EF with MVC? What can I do to prevent having to sprinkle in those lines of code every time I have a value with a special character?

Thanks!!

Comment: _"using the C# escape characters"_ - nope, that's only when applying `@` to a [verbatim string literal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx) (`@"C:\Foo.bar"`) or when you want to use a [keyword as identifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x53a06bb) (`string @string`). Slamming an `@` in front of a variable name doesn't do anything to the contents of that variable. Please just run the SQL Profiler and see what query is sent to the server.

Comment: what is datatype for     email and phone

Comment: `<Property Name="Phone" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="25" />` `<Property Name="EmailAddress" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="50" />`

Comment: Can you trim down the test case? Use a new `person` entity where you simply set `person.EmailAddress = "foo@bar.baz"` and attempt to save it, check if it works. If it does (and it should), check (**debug**) a `person` that has been `InjectFrom`'ed. Inspect the `person.EmailAddress`. If then you can't find anything weird, use SQL Server Profiler.

Comment: Ok. tried to increase maxlength to say Nvarchar 300?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well in typical fasion I figure it out 10 seconds after posting the question that I have spent 3 hours trying to figure out:

As @CodeMaster noted, those lines of code were incorrect anyway. I started playing with some of the other fields and I figured out the culprit.

The code smaple I gave was condensed for brevity, but I was injecting into (2) different entites: Person and Contact. It turns out *both* tables have a 'Title' field. I was only focused on the 'Title' field in the Person table which had a length of '50' like below:

`<Property Name="Title" Type="nvarchar" Nullable="false" MaxLength="50" />`

It turns out the Contact field had the exact smae field I was unaware of but only a length of '8' as below:

`<Property Name="Title" Type="nvarchar" MaxLength="8" />`

This caused the error and it *was indeed* legitimate. ValueInjecter mapped the same single 'Title' value to both entities when I only wanted the one and caused the issue. Have to be careful because ValueInjectoer does not discriminate if names match (as it should not) but this cause my problem.